# Applying custom face in emacs

Tags: emacs, face

I wanted to make a derived mode for `python-mode` to add custom keywords and color. So I retreived the part of the code that defines the face of the keywords and added my own keywords.

If I use an already existing face it works just fine. But I want to use custom faces so it doesn't change color if in the same time of other faces.
I search how to define a face and end up with this:

```
(defface printr-face
  '((t :foreground "red" :weight bold))
  "Face for printr function"
  :group 'python-print-color-faces)
```

the part of the code I try to apply it (inside the variable "python-font-lock-keywords") look like this:

```
(,(rx symbol-start (or "printr") symbol-end) . printr-face)
```

The `printr-face` does appear in the list when I use 
`M-x list-faces-display`.

But the face isn't applied.  `M-x describe-face` see it as default.

What am I doing wrong? How can I use my newly defined face ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

choroba was in the right.
Also I missed a set a parenthesis in the defface:

```
(defface printr-face `((t (:foreground "red" :weight bold))) "Face for printr function"
  :group  'python-print-color)
```

(I forgot to encapsulated the :forground :weight)

then

```
 (font-lock-add-keywords
 'python-print-color-mode
 '(("printr" . 'printr)
   ("printg" . 'printg)))
```

Note that I had to use "." instead of "1" to make it work. Not sure what the "1" should have done but it wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

When adding new faces to new keywords, you need to add the keywords, too:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 'my-mode
 '(("regex1" 1 'my-face1)
   ("regex2" 1 'my-face2))
 1)
```

Comment: the `(,(rx symbol-start (or "printr") symbol-end) . printr-face)` is define in the "python-font-lock-keywords" along the other normal keywords of python. And it's not working. Not because of the keyword itself but the face. The keyword doesn't turn red. (If I use a existant face it does change color but I wan't to use my own)

Comment: Scratch that, it only work with face that are already use within the font-lock-keywords. Another normal face isn't apply either. Weird.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the ', that is why your solution iddn't work. But it does when I don't forget it. Also My definition of the face was lacking a set of parentheses I think